# Sony Xperia SP (C5303) + Cyanogen

Tags: cyanogenmod, flashtool

I tried to follow article on http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_huashan#Unlock_your_Xperia_SP

to flash Cyanogen on my Xperia SP.

I used flashtool to get into fastboot. I got unlock key from Sony page, I unlocked bootloader.

Then I followed step:

- Extract boot.img from the zip to your computer, you will need this file for fastboot.
- Put the phone into fastboot mode:
  With the device powered down, hold Volume Up and connect the USB cable. The notification light should turn blue to indicate you are in fastboot mode.
- Open a terminal on the PC and enter the following:
  `fastboot flash boot boot.img`
  `fastboot reboot`

After reboot I got black screen, no Led, but Device gets connected in Win as: `Sony sa0108 ADB Interface Driver`

However I cannot get `adb` running.

There is also one more device with question mark in list as `C5303`

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The boot.img contains the new kernel and the ramdisk, but not the Android system, which can be in system.img and may need to be flashed separately (though the recovery should usually do both if you use a .zip) -- that said, it looks from those instructions like you're supposed to mess with the volume rockers to boot into recovery mode, then do a factory reset.  Also, there was an announcement today for Sony devices that you might want to [look at](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/public-service-announcement-sony-cm12-users) as well.  Good luck!

Comment: Thx, but problem is that while phone is in ADB mode, I cannot reboot it via adb because device is not authorized, and cannot authorize because I see only black with lcd backlight. I cannot even reboot it via buttons combination. I have to wait until battery dies :(

Comment: Great I just managed to connect phone over Sony Emma, and just recovering it to stock.

Comment: Great.  Glad it's working now...

Comment: I used EMMA tool, but it stuck while sending image to phone. Phone looks now worse than before, only red led light, and if i connect to PC, pc does not recognize driver for device :(